# Определить перекрыт ли элемент другим элементом

Tags: javascript, css, css3, z-index

Возможно ли определить перекрытие элемента другим элементом, при условии что не известен элемент который будет перекрывать?

```js
var e = document.getElementById('e');
var eR = e.getBoundingClientRect();

var all = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
 var cR = all[i].getBoundingClientRect();
 if(all[i] != e) {
  if (((cR.top <= eR.top) && (eR.top <= cR.bottom)) &&
     ((cR.top <= eR.bottom) && (eR.bottom <= cR.bottom)) &&
     ((cR.left <= eR.left) && (eR.left <= cR.right)) &&
     ((cR.left <= eR.right) && (eR.right <= cR.right))) {
         //var inside = true;
         var style = window.getComputedStyle ? getComputedStyle(all[i]) : all[i].currentStyle;
         if(style.zIndex >= 1) {
           var overlap = true;
              console.log(style.zIndex);
          }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.wrap {
  width:700px;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:600px;
  background-color:yellow;
  z-index:9999;
}  
.behind {
  position: absolute;
  left:8px;
  top:0px;
  width:468px;
  height:160px;
  background-color:rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.71);
  z-index: 999;
}
.container {
  background-color:black;
  left:20px;
  top:50px;
  width:468px;
  height:60px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div class="behind"></div>
<div class="container" id='e'>ad</div>
</div>
```

[Пример на JSFiddle UPD](http://jsfiddle.net/rd2d2/b1ooy05y/16/)

Вот что получилось, проблема в том, что если у родителя (.wrap) стоит z-index >0 он не перекрывает потомка (.container), а скрипт проверяет это условие и получается ложное перекрытие.
Я правильно понимаю что родитель может перекрыть потомка только если у потомка отрицательный z-index?

Comment: JQuery plugin подойдет? https://plugins.jquery.com/overlaps/ (вот работающий пример http://yckart.github.io/jquery.overlaps.js/ - там все из кода вытащить можно)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант, можно получить х,у координаты нашего "container" элемента и его х,у + его размер. Далее, пройтись циклом по всему DOM (по всем элементам, исключая наш "container") и проверять их координаты учитывая размеры и параметр z-index, который должен быть меньше чем у "container" в случае если есть совпадения координат. Это все можно или на Javascript сделать, или с JQuery.

Например, с JQuery: http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-coordinates-element/

```
var ctrxCoord = $(".container").offset().left;
var ctryCoord = $(".container").offset().top;
var ctrwidthCoord = ctrxCoord + $(".container").width();
var ctrheightCoord = ctryCoord + $(".container").height();
```

Нужно проверить, возможно, для добавления, нужно делать с parseInt(ctryCoord) ...

Больше информации (англ.): https://stackoverflow.com/a/21274679/873481
и http://www.dyn-web.com/javascript/element-location/

Думаю, комментарий cyadvert может также быть верным.

Еще вариант - document.elementFromPoint https://stackoverflow.com/a/3942852/873481

Comment: @rd2d2
Если будете искать по DOM с помощью JQuery, используйте селекторы http://www.elated.com/articles/jquery-selectors/
Вот, например, для поиска: `$("body").find("*").filter(function() { return $(this).offset().top == top && $(this).offset().left == left; });`и, вместо `$(this).offset().left`, можно подставить селектор jquery...

Comment: Только вот, проходить по всему дереву, проверяя координаты и z-index, будет накладно по производительности, если элементов очень много..

Comment: @rd2d2
Используйте Jquery, может, пример, который я показал в комментарии выше. не думаю что с помощью такого способа уйдет много времени и ресурсов на поиск, не должно!

Comment: Вот что получилось http://jsfiddle.net/rd2d2/b1ooy05y/15/
Проблема в том, что если у родителя (.wrap) стоит z-index >0 он не перекрывает потомка (.container), а скрипт проверяет это условие и получается ложное перекрытие. Как это можно проверить?

Comment: upd: http://jsfiddle.net/rd2d2/b1ooy05y/16/

Comment: @rd2d2
Возможно, з-индекс относителен к родительскому элементу + css атрибут position может влиять.

Answer (score 1):

Можно получить точки для прямоугольника через offset и длину/ширину элемента и по ним определить пересечение.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function getPositionRect(jObject){
      return { 
               x0 : jObject.offset().top, y0 : jObject.offset().left, 
               x1 : jObject.offset().top + jObject.width(), y1 : jObject.offset().left + jObject.height() 
             };
  }
  function intersects(a, b){
       return ( a.y0 < b.y1 || a.y1 > b.y0 || a.x1 < b.x0 || a.x0 > b.x1 );
  }

  var overlap = $($('.overlap').eq(0)),
      container = $($('.container').eq(0));

  console.log(
      intersects(getPositionRect(overlap),getPositionRect(container))
  );
});
```

Comment: Не подойдёт, тк. условие: перекрываемый элемент (элементы) заранее не известен.
Желательно на чистом JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Можно заюзать такой метод: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect
вернёт координаты прямоугольников. А там уже легко проверить пересечение.